# DataTrigger not firing when bound dependency property changes

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

A `DataTrigger` exists within a `ControlTemplate`

```
<DataTrigger
    Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, 
              Path=(ui:TreeViewItemHeader.IsDragTarget)}"
    Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="PART_Content" Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
</DataTrigger>
```

The bound property, IsDragTarget, is an attached property which is coded in to a custom control class:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDragTargetProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
        ("IsDragTarget", 
        typeof(bool), 
        typeof(TreeViewItemHeader),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

public static void SetIsDragTarget(DependencyObject self, bool value)
{
    self.SetValue(IsDragTargetProperty, value);
}

public static bool GetIsDragTarget(DependencyObject self)
{
    return (bool)self.GetValue(IsDragTargetProperty);
}
```

The problem may be described that the `DataTrigger` only appears to resolve the value once, when the control is initialized. Updating the property value does not flip the DataTrigger.

Troubleshooting performed:

- A blank `IValueConverter` "return value" was added to the binding; the `IValueConverter.Convert` method is being called only once.
- Debug stepping was performed to verify that the attached property value is changed.
- The `DataTrigger.Value` property was set to `False` - the initial value of the attached property; the Setters fired once when the control intialized. Subsequent changes to the property did not fire the DataTrigger.
- The Visual Studio Output window shows no binding expression warnings.

Comment: Does `PART_Content` define a Foreground color in the `<Tag>` definition? If so, that value will overwrite any triggered values

Comment: @Rachel- No, it doesn't, but thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it a strict requirement to use `DataTrigger`? I've got it working by switching to `Trigger`:

```
<Trigger Property="ui:TreeViewItemHeader.IsDragTarget" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="PART_Content" Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
</Trigger>
```

Don't know why `DataTrigger` is not working though.

Comment: From the documentation.  Represents a trigger that applies property values or performs actions when the bound data meets a specified condition.  I guess a Property is not bound data.

Comment: I'm not really sure why I used a DataTrigger. I think I tricked myself in to believing it was required because of the fact that I was writing the trigger inside of a ControlTemplate, and couldn't use the Trigger.SourceName Property to reference the UserControl root. Your post gave me the epiphany that I didn't need SourceName at all. It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to raise property value changing events by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface

As shown in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2482402/468718)

Comment: Hi Harsh. The property is actually an attached dependency property, so I don't believe INotifyPropertyChanged is required.

Comment: WPF is based mainly on Property System and as the value changes we need to call property change notification which wpf handles

Comment: I think you had better read [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx).

Comment: ok, I did not noticed earlier that it is Attached Property, not Dependency Property..

Comment: but check this article which uses lil'bit of diff way for Attached Properties.. http://www.deanchalk.me.uk/post/WPF-e28093-Using-Attached-Properties-For-Animated-Data-Change-Notifications.aspx and also take care of this issue while using the link given.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4297488/468718   :D

Comment: Harsh- Your explain shows an attached property which has side effects, handled in the OnChanged event handler. This is unnecessary in my case, as I can produce the side effects through a simple Trigger/DataTrigger.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the getter & setter be defined something like:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDragTargetProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
        ("IsDragTarget",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(TreeViewItemHeader),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

public bool IsDragTarget {
            get { return (bool)this.GetValue(IsDragTargetProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(IsDragTargetProperty, value); }
        }
```

Comment: Loxxy- You'd be write if we were talking about a dependency property. We're actually talking about an attached property.